Error in Power Query when accessing SharePoint folder in Microsoft Fabric dataflow
I'm new to Microsoft Fabric and was assigned a task to create a dataflow and pipeline. I need to retrieve a list of CSV files from a specific SharePoint folder. I previously used the following expression to fetch data from a specific folder, and it worked well in other dataflow creations. However, today, while creating a new dataflow using Power Query, this expression reading the steps but after publishing it refreshing stage we are getting a caution symbol with the following error message.
SharePoint.Contents("https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/Solutions/DocumentStorage", [ApiVersion = 15])
There was a problem refreshing the dataflow. Please review the error message(s) below, fix the problem, and try again.
SharePoint list: Error Code: Mashup Exception Expression Error, Error Details: Couldn't refresh the entity because of an issue with the mashup document MashupException.Error: Expression.Error: Failed to insert a table., InnerException: We cannot convert a value of type Table to type Text., Underlying error: We cannot convert a value of type Table to type Text. Details: Reason = Expression.Error;Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ErrorCode = Lakehouse036;Message = We cannot convert a value of type Table to type Text.;Message.Format = We cannot convert a value of type #{0} to type #{1}.;Message.Parameters = {"Table", "Text"};ErrorCode = 10276;Microsoft.Data.Mashup.Error.Context = User
Warning: SharePoint list: Fast Copy is not supported for any of the data sources in the expression:
